# Kan extension of subfunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $i: A \to B$ be a fully faithful embedding (dense if it helps) of categories and $F:A \to C$ be a functor with $C$ being complete. Assume that the right Kan extension of $F$ along $i$ is limit preserving, given a subfunctor $F'$ of $F$, is the right Kan extension of $F'$ along $i$ in general limit preserving too? If no, can we put any reasonable conditions (not too restrictive) on the categories/functors so that this becomes true?

Comment: I have the gut feeling that for $Ran_iF$ preserving (say) products is a rare condition; maybe try with $i$ = Yoneda and find a small counterexample?

Comment: Hi @Fosco. One example in my mind is as follows: let $A$ be a fully faithful dense subcategory of $B$, $C=Sets$, $a$ be an object of $A$ and $F=Hom_A(a,-)$. Then I think  $Ran_iF=Hom_B(a,-)$ which is limit preserving. But is $Ran_iF'$ limit preserving?

Comment: It seems to me $Ran_iF$ is $B(ja,\_)$ if $j$ is fully faithful and dense, but this is a back-of-the-envelope calculation, you should check carefully. In general, $Ran_iF'$ is not well-behaved. For example, if $F'$ is the minimal subobject of $A(a,\_)$, $Ran_iF'$ is the terminal functor.

Comment: Oh, but probably in that case the resulting functor is limit preserving without conditions on $A$. Let me think more thoroughly.

Comment: @Fosco what's your $j$ here? Anyway I think $Ran_iF$ should be really the actual extension which thus has to be $Hom_B(i(a),-)$?  For $Ran_iF'$ I believe it has to be a subfunctor of $Hom_B(i(a),-)$? If this is true, we're really asking what subfunctors of $Hom_B(i(a),-)$  necessarily preserve limit.